# How to save multiple Entries to xml through Serialization in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a c# Application which I got as a task for school, I have to be able to use Serialization to save data to xml. So far I am able to save one instance of a class for example Customer. But when I enter a new data the old one is overwritten and there is just one data available. Can someone maybe look at my code and tell me where I am wrong?

serializationClass here are my methods to serialize or deserialize my xml:

```
namespace Aufgabe_1
{
    class serializerHelper
    {
        public void XmlSerialize(Type data, object objectData, string fileName)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append)) 
            {
                XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(data);
                xSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, objectData);
            }
        
        }

        public object showData(Type dataType, string fileName)
        {
            object obj;
           
          XmlSerializer xSerializer2 = new XmlSerializer(dataType);

            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
            obj = xSerializer2.Deserialize(textReader);

            return obj;
        
        }
        }
```

My class which I try to save data to xml:

```
namespace Aufgabe_1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Kunde
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public string adress;
        public string birthday;
        public string bankDetails;

        public Kunde() { }
       

       public Kunde(string firstname, string lastname, string adress, string birthday, string bankdetails)
       
       {
         this.firstName = firstname;
           this.lastName = lastname;
            this.adress = adress;
            this.birthday = birthday;
           this.bankDetails = bankdetails;

        }

        public  bool saveCustomer()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Namen des Kunden ein!");
           string firstNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Nachnamen des Kunden ein!");
            string lastNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Adresse des Kunden ein!");
            string adressInput =  Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Geburtsdatum des Kunden ein!");
            string birthdayInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Bankdetails des Kunden ein!");
            string bankDetailsInput = Console.ReadLine();

            Kunde customer = new Kunde(firstNameInput, lastNameInput, adressInput, birthdayInput, bankDetailsInput);
            Console.Clear();

           string filePath = "customerDatabase2.xml";
        serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
        if (File.Exists("customerDatabase2.xml"))
        {
            kList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Kunde>), filePath) as List<Kunde>;

        }

        kList.Add(customer);

        sHelper.XmlSerialize(typeof(List<Kunde>), kList, filePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Ihr Kunde wurde gespeichert danke für die Zusammenarbeit!");

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Drücken Sie 1 um ins Hauptmenü zu gelangen und auf 2 um die Applikation zu beenden!");
        Program p = new Program();


            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1": Program.menuPoints(); return true;
                case "2": Environment.Exit(0); return true;
               
            }
            return true;
        }


        public void showCustomers()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Hier sind Ihre Kunden!");

            string filePath = "customerDatabase.xml";
            serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
            Kunde k;
           k = sHelper.showData(typeof(Kunde),filePath) as Kunde;
            Console.WriteLine("Vorname" + "Nachname" + "Adresse" + "Geburtsdatum" + "Bankdaten");
           Console.WriteLine(k.firstName + k.lastName + k.adress + k.birthday + k.bankDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of FileMode.Create I tried .Append, with this I could save multiple instances of class Kunde but then I was getting an error in my xml and could not deserialize it anymore.

Comment: You need to add a root class that contains a list of Kunde.  Public class Root { public List<Kunde> Kundes { get;set;}}

Comment: do I have to do this inside my current class or as a seperate class? The root class I mean

Comment: A separate class.  The use new class and change type : sHelper.showData(typeof(Kundes),filePath) as Kundes;

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `.Append`, I would suggest you keep `.Create` and read/write a list of `Kunde` instances.  Where you read your list and add to it and when you save, you save the entire list.

So in keeping with the layout of your post, you might try somthing like this:

```cs
            Kunde customer = new Kunde(firstNameInput, lastNameInput, adressInput, birthdayInput, bankDetailsInput);
            Console.Clear();

            string filePath = "customerDatabase.xml";
            serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
            // This is assuming you have a valid file to begin with
            List<Kunde> kList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Kunde>),filePath) as List<Kunde>;
            kList.Add(customer);

            sHelper.XmlSerialize(typeof(List<Kunde>), kList, filePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Ihr Kunde wurde gespeichert danke für die Zusammenarbeit!");
```

And within your showCustomers(), something similar to this:

```cs
            serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
            List<Kunde> kList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Kunde>),filePath) as List<Kunde>;
            foreach(var k in kList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vorname" + "Nachname" + "Adresse" + "Geburtsdatum" + "Bankdaten");
                Console.WriteLine(k.firstName + k.lastName + k.adress + k.birthday + k.bankDetails);
            }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but when I try to add another one I get this error:the process can not access "customerDatabase2.xml" because it is being used by another process. But I closed and reopend the application and still the same error. I edited my code to implement your method

Comment: In the internet it said I had to close the stream I tried that but still no luck. If I take the if part away it works. But then the xml is overwritten again.

Comment: Make sure you close your file in `showData`, e.g., put a `using` around `TextReader...`.   Be sure you did change back to `FileMode.Create` in `XmlSerialize`.  Another thing you should do is make sure kList is created if it (the file) doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks now it works. Can u maybe explain me what using did?

Comment: It basically ensures that what you are using is disposed and there is a much longer explaination [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) but in order to use 'using' the class must implement `IDisposible`.